# RBinding Multiple dfs from Excel Files

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, xlsx, rbind

I am currently working on combining my data from multiple excel files into one df. Problem is, the number of columns differ across the files (due to different experiment versions), so I need to bind only certain columns/variables from each file (they have the same names).

I tried doing this "manually" at first, using:

```
library(openxlsx)
PWI <- read.xlsx("/Users/myname/Desktop/PrelimPWI/PWI_1_V1A.xlsx", colNames = TRUE, startRow = 2)
Slim_1 <- data.frame(PWI$Subject, PWI$Block, PWI$Category, PWI$Trial,PWI$prompt1.RT)
#read in and pull out variables of interest for one subject
mergedFullData = merge(mergedDataA, mergedDataB) 
#add two together, then add the third to the merged file, add 4th to that merged file, etc
```

Obviously, it seems like there's a simpler way to combine the files. I've been working on using:

```
library(openxlsx)

path <- "/Users/myname/Desktop/PrelimPWI"
merge_file_name <- "/Users/myname/Desktop/PrelimPWI/merge_file_name.xlsx"

filenames_list <- list.files(path= path, full.names=TRUE)

All <- lapply(filenames_list,function(merge_file_name$Subject){
  print(paste("Merging",merge_file_name,sep = " "))
  read.xlsx(merge_file_name, colNames=TRUE, startRow = 2)
})
PWI <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, All)
write.xlsx(PWI,merge_file_name)
```

However, I keep getting the error that the number of columns doesn't match, but I'm not sure where to pull out the specific variables I need (the ones listed in the earlier code). Any other tweaks I've tried has resulted in only the first file being written into the xlsx, or a completely blank df. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(
  a = c(1,2,3),
  x = c(4,5,6)
)

df2 <- tibble(
  x = c(7,8,9),
  y = c("d","e","f")
)

bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

The `bind` functions from `dplyr` should be able to help you. They can bind dataframes together by row or column, and are flexible about different column names.

You can then select the actual columns you want to keep.